# Trying to add a new directory in the root of my server

Tags: linux, ssh, directory-structure, dedicated-server

just moved from shared hosting to a dedicated server, trying to create two new directorys in the root of the server but I get this when I use the Plesk control panel

Error: Unable to create directory /other-files: filemng: Error occurred during /bin/mkdir command.

So I tried executing this

```
$old_umask = umask(0);
$return = mkdir('../other-files', 0770);
umask($old_umask);
var_dump($return);
```

which returns false

I've downloaded putty but I've never used SSH commands and to my understanding I think I need to create the folder as a root user, but I really don't want to do something wrong and I don't think I can log in as the root user, but I can execute a su command which seems to be what I need to do... any help?

Comment: do you know the name of the linux distribution that you use? what's the output of whoami

Comment: @hovanessyan do you mean type whoami into the command line? Well I did and it just outputted the username I set up for the server, and is this it? - OS: Linux CentOS 64-Bit

Comment: Ok so if you want to create directory 'foo', just try: su <enter>, you will be prompted for pass, and than '/bin/mkdir /foo'.

Comment: # /bin/mkdir/other-files
bash: /bin/mkdir/other-files: Not a directory

@hovanessyan - that is the response

Comment: you are missing a space, the command should be '/bin/mkdir /other-files' assuming you want to create top-level direcoty called 'other-files'

Comment: it's not a good idea, you should define working user (different from root) and use the home folder of that user for the everyday work etc.

Comment: okay it allowed the command but no response, so I've checked my root directory and it doesn't seem to have worked

Comment: i think i may do it differently @hovanessyan

Comment: navigate to the directory, where you expect the folder to appear. Paste the output of 'pwd'

Comment: [root@ip- ecminion]# /bin/mkdir /other-files
[root@ip- ecminion]# cd /bin
[root@ip- bin]# pwd
/bin
[root@ip- bin]# cd ~
[root@ip- ~]# pwd
/root
[root@ip- ~]#
[root@ip- ~]#
[root@ip- ~]# /bin/mkdir /other-files
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory `/other-files': File exists
[root@ip- ~]#

@hovanessyan

Comment: if I run this from the main domain of the server $filename = "../other-files";
if (file_exists($filename)) {
 echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
 echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}

it says it doesn't exist

Comment: In Linux / is called 'the root', if you want to create folder under /root, you have to execute '/bin/mkdir /root/other-files'. /root is the 'home directory' of the root user, and / is the ROOT of them all.

Comment: Check out this guide http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/usersguide/linux_ugfilestruct.html and you should really read more before taking VPS to use or (god forbid) administer.

Comment: thanks! I really should probably delete the folder I just put in root I think I meant home...

Comment: yeah - you can delete it using rmdir (the directory should be empty).